# jQuery slidetoggle not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-slide-effects

http://jsfiddle.net/nKUgA/2/

I'm just trying to make a small box slide down from the pictureControls div which acts as a button, but slideToggle is doing nothing-- it just sort of glitches into place and back again. Read a *ton* of other similar questions, none helped or applied.

```
    $('#pictureControls').click(function(event) {
        $('#pictureControlsMenu').slideToggle(300);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to embed jQuery in that fiddle.

Comment: Oh, bingo. That would do it.

Comment: jQuery UI as well, for the slider widget.

Comment: But why can I not see the picture resource in the first place?

Comment: A couple things, real quicklike: 1) You don't have jQuery support turned on in the left sidebar of jsFiddle, and 2) You're trying to use background images with urls pointing at a local directory, which you can't do inside jsFiddle and expect the images to show up.

Comment: There, fully working fiddle edited in. Except for the slide effect, of course.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`slideToggle` wasn't working because the table is not a block element.  In the following update I've made it a block element (instead of display:none), and then hidden it on page load with jQuery...

http://jsfiddle.net/nKUgA/4/

Comment: Nice. Probably a better fix than mine.

Comment: @isherwood Something I wasn't aware of till now, tbh.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much. Could you kindly explain why making it a `block` element is necessary? Are divs inherently `block` elements while tables have to be specified?

Comment: Tables are inline and divs are block - yes.  As to why that's an issue with slideToggle I honestly don't know.  It was just the first thing I thought of when I saw your problem.  You could also try putting the table in a div and see if that still works, but there's obviously no real need now ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try sliding a div rather than the table:

http://jsfiddle.net/nKUgA/3/

```
<div id="pictureControls" onclick="" title="Picture Controls" alt="Picture Controls">
    <div id="pictureControlsWrapper">
        <table id="pictureControlsMenu">
```

Since I wasn't sure what the HTML click function and the other thing were doing, I removed them along with the stopPropogation statement.

Comment: I seem to recall reading quite some time ago that tables didn't react nicely to being resized... I'm betting that's why wrapping the table in a div works, rather than trying to perform the slideToggle() directly on the table itself.

Comment: What's strange is that the jQuery team lists this bug as being "fixed" - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2185 ... it originates from issues with non block-level elements.

Comment: A keen suggestion and I think you're right about the table somehow but the animation movement from this code for some reason is still a bit glitchy-- Archer's method yields the perfect slide.